# How to inject logger using Google Guice

Tags: java, logging, guice

Usually I define logger like this:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

But when using `@Inject` we must use non-static and non-final field, like:

```
@Inject
private Logger logger;
```

i.e. logger will be created in each instance of this class, also logger is mutable. May be exist some way to make logger static? Also how I can bind logger to certain class (I use send the class object when creating logger object from factory `LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`, how to create logger in same way using injecting ? )?

Comment: What's the reason for logger to be injected? Is it only to avoid some typing?

Comment: It might be useful to constructor-inject a logger if you want to test that some log lines are written.

Answer (score 8):

Please check the [Custom Injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections#example-injecting-a-log4j-logger) on Guice wiki, there is a complete Log4J example.

EDIT: You can use either a `static` field or a `final` field for your logger, but not a `static final` one. This is a Java [limitation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).

Also be wary [that](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections#example-injecting-a-log4j-logger):

> Injecting final fields is not recommended because the injected value may not be visible to other threads.

Haven't tested that but the code in the article should work fine for static fields, although you could improve it by getting rid of MembersInjector and doing all of it in the TypeListener (since a static field needs to be set only once).

Using `requestStaticInjection()` will force you to list all your classes in a module file - not a good idea, as you will soon forget to add one.

OTOH if you just want to support JUL you might be better of using the [built-in support](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BuiltInBindings#loggers) (as mentioned by Jeff, I assumed you didn't want a general answer, since you didn't mention JUL specifically in your question).

Comment: I find the linked article lacking in several aspects: 1) A new annotation is required. For JUL you can use @Inject(both java.inject.Inject and Guice's one). 2) No constructor injection is supported, 3) no method injection is supported 4) Superclasses are only supported by hacks in the comments. Summary so far: JUL support is special and cannot be transferred to other logging frameworks in the same manner and quality.

Comment: Sorry, I find this not constuctive or relevant for my anwser. 
1) No it isn't you can just drop the check and inject all Logger fields
2) Yes, but how do you expect that to work with Guice?
3) It is supported, you can inspect the class in whatever way you want (e.g. look for methods)

Comment: My point, which is relevant to your answer, is this: the linked article has its drawbacks. The proposed solution there does not support injection in the same way Guice supports injection elsewhere. These differences should be clear _upfront_ and not after the facts. Especially as the last part of the question ("how to create...") and the use of `@Inject` seems to address exactly this IMO. <br>
I named the three issues I had in a similar case. This is not against you but only for everyone who wants to explore that solution - If they say "I can live with these thing." OK - be welcome.

Comment: To address your points: 1) If you don't use annotations at all then you deviate from Guice's normal mode of operation even more. I call this "surprising behaviour" (something good frameworks should avoid) when field are injected without any sign why, when, and by whom. And you cannot use `@Inject` as everywhere else. Try it. 2) That's exactly the missing point (or link) where Guice does handle JUL differently than everybody else without a known way around this. 3) Many things can be done, but the linked article doesn't do it.

Comment: Those things are true (except 4), however there is no way to go around them in Guice. They would be relevant if the question was about any DI, but since it's a question about injecting a logger with Guice I think it's moot to complain about Guice design choices.
@4) I don't think it's justifiable to call those "hacks" -- this is computer programming. I assume anybody reading this is accustomed with the way Java reflection works.

Comment: Reagrding 4): I chose the term "hack" not because it is obscure or not understandable but because I consider a comment in a wiki not as a part of the official documentation. I think if the Guice developers would care or find the improvements valuable they would have fixed the article.

Answer (score 4):

When designing your application for dependency injection, typically the best practice is to avoid static fields and methods as much as possible. This is so that your dependencies are clearer, and so it's easier to replace your real dependencies with other instances during tests and as your application evolves. The ideal behavior, therefore, is to avoid static methods and fields (including loggers) as much as possible.

Guice, however, does allow for marking fields static, and [requesting injection of static fields when the Injector is created](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#Static_Injections). The fields will need to remain mutable--`final` doesn't mean "final except for Guice".

```
public class YourClass {
  @Inject static Logger logger;

  /* ... */
}

public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    /* YourClass.logger will work once you create your Injector. */
    requestStaticInjection(YourClass.class);
  }
}
```

Guice automatically provides [`java.util.logger.Logger` instances](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) for you with the class name embedded into it, but that's only because of [a special case coded into Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/InjectorShell.java#247). If you want a special logger, as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605198/how-do-i-get-google-guice-to-inject-a-custom-logger-say-a-commons-logging-or-lo), you'll need to investigate the Custom Injections to which Jakub linked--but if the whole goal is to centralize logger creation so you can control it in one place, you can just refactor that into a static factory outside of Guice too.

```
@LogToFile
public class YourClass {
  private static final Logger logger = YourLoggerFactory.create(YourClass.class);

  /* ... */
}

public class YourLoggerFactory {
  private YourLoggerFactory { /* do not instantiate */ }

  public Logger create(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz.getAnnotation(LogToFile.class) != null) {
      return someImplementation(new File(...));
    } else {
      return someOtherImplementation();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has the drawback, that the name of the class, `Yourclass.class` in your example, must be provided in a consistent manner throughout all applications. That _might_ be exactly one of the reasons why centralized injection is considered and helpful - that problem would not exist with proper injection support.

Comment: @A.H. Note that the ability for a provider or dependency to determine its injection site was [explicitly and deliberately rejected as a feature](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=27). In an instance field, you could use `this`, but in a static context Java sadly doesn't have any syntax shorter than the class name itself. When you find or create "proper injection support", please pass it along--I'd be very happy to see how it works!

Comment: Note that Guice *does* allow injection of final fields, see my answer above for a link.